# Regression model for predicting life expectancy

Tags: r, regression, time-series, forecasting, mortality

I have average life expectancy at birth data for an 8 year period and I would like to use that 8 year period to predict the trend for average life expectancy for the next 5 years. I would then like to ask whether this deviates significantly from the actual average life expectancy over the next 5 years.

1. What's the best regression model to fit to the observation base data in order to get predictions for next 5 years?
2. How can I assess whether the difference between the predicted and observed trend is significant?
3. How can I implement #1 and #2 in R?